# iframe video array

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to make it so when I click the 'next' button it will increment the variable videoCounter and then reload the iframe so it plays the next video in the array.
Currently it just seems to reload the whole page and do nothing?

```
<script>
  var videoCounter = 0;
  var videoArray = new Array();
  videoArray[0] = "//www.youtube.com/embed/nEBHkEeH42Y";
  videoArray[1] = "//www.youtube.com/embed/1GlticqrECU",
  videoArray[2] = "//www.youtube.com/embed/BMOUsI8JIaI";

  function Increment() {
    videoCounter++;
    ReloadIFrame();
  }

  function ReloadIFrame() {
    SetCurrentVideo();
    document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
  }

  function SetCurrentVideo() {
    document.getElementById("iframe").src = videoArray[videoCounter];
  }
</script>

<iframe id="iframe" width="520" height="280" src="SetCurrentVideo();"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<ul class="pager">
  <li class="previous disabled" id="videoOlder"><a href="">&larr; Older</a>
  </li>
  <li id="videoTitle">Title here</li>
  <li class="next" id="videoNewer" onclick="Increment();"> <a href="">Newer &rarr;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That’s because you have a link pointing to the same page `<a href="">`, and you are not preventing its _default_ behaviour from happening when it gets clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the page reloads because clicking on the `a` tag causes the browser to send the user to the destination of the link - because you haven't put a URL in the `href` of this link, the destination is the current page.

Each time the page loads, the value of `videoCounter` is reinitialised to 0; it appears to reload and do nothing because it's always loading the first video again.

To prevent the default behaviour of an anchor (`a` tag) you need to `return false;` from the handler:

```
function Increment() {
    videoCounter++;
    ReloadIFrame();

    return false;
}
```

*Update*; you also have a syntax error on the second line (a comma instead of a semi-colon), which may be preventing the rest of your code from being defined.

Here's a full working example for you:

> **http://jsfiddle.net/UqXVf/1/**

Comment: still just reloads the page

Comment: You might need to use `e.preventDefault()` instead of `return false`.